# how to get data when cell accessory is tapped in ios

Tags: ios, swift, segue, cell, accessory

i have tableview which has several cells, when user tap on the cell it does some other function and when cell accessory is tapped i want it to segue to another view controller
i am able to do so but the problem is i am not able to send the data at cell indexpath row, in order to send data i first have to touch the cell then tap on accessory to send the data here is the code for tableview

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
    myTableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.identifier {
    case "ShowDetail":
        if let ip = myTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
            if let svc = segue.destination as? DetailViewController{
                svc.selectedObject = (myCounters?[ip.row])!
            }
        }
    default:
        print("error in segue")
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `performSegue` method?

Comment: i am not calling perform segue i m using prepare for segue and also i tried perform segue and tried sending value through sender but that also did not work

Comment: First: calling `myTableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)` in `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith` seems to be weird to me if you are aiming to do different functionality rather than selecting the cell. Second: I'd assume that there is a `performSegue` somewhere in your code. You said "perform segue and tried sending value through sender but that also did not work", would you explain how?

Comment: in perform segue we have 2 placeholder in first i am writing segue identifier in second i am writing indexpath.row

Comment: I would suggest to provide the code for perform segue and mention the issue, you should achieve it using perform segue if I got it right...

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
        inindex = indexPath
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowDetail", sender: nil)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        switch segue.identifier {
        case "ShowDetail":
            if let ip = inindex{
                if let svc = segue.destination as? DetailViewController{
                    svc.selectedObject = (myCounters?[ip.row])!
                }
            }
    }

Comment: Would you please add it to the question instead of a comment? Also, please mention what's the problem in your code at this point.

Comment: i got the answer , i removed the segue connection and use instantiate view controller as detail view controller to pass data in cell accessory tapped method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "detailvc") as? DetailViewController
vc?.selectedObject = (myCounters?[indexPath.row])!
navigationController?.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: like if i select accessory of first cell this time it opens up an controller with nothing in it and when i close that controller i am back to previous controller only new thing here is that cell whose accessory i tapped is selected this time so now if i press accessory of any cell the data of first cell is going to pass to the view controller

Comment: perform the segue programatically

Comment: i have edited my answer, and you should remove segue from storyboard.

Comment: if it still doesn't work you can instantiate the controller using storyboardId and present or push it..

Comment: same with instantiate view controller i am not getting crash either just a view controller with label and button without value are showing

Comment: it worked!!! i forgot to remove segue connection before trying instantiate view controller my bad , how can i upvote this comment

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @shahzaib qureshi
i removed the segue connection and use instantiate view controller method as detail view controller in cell accessory tapped method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "detailvc") as? DetailViewController
    vc?.selectedObject = (myCounters?[indexPath.row])!
    navigationController?.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    print("ewwewew")
}
```

Comment: edit your answer to correct and i will upvote it thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the index path in the `sender` parameter, pretty easy:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowDetail", sender: indexPath) 
} 

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) { 
   if segue.identifier == "ShowDetail" { 
       let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
       let svc = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
       svc.selectedObject = myCounters![indexPath.row]
   }
}
```

Comment: doesnt work i tried i have given my answer its working

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Index : \(indexPath.row)")

    var tempIndex: Int!
    var tempIdentifier: String!

    self.tempIndex = indexPath.row //You can store indexpath.row value in temp variable. And then then you can access it while performing any other functions.
    self.tempIdentifier = "ShowDetail" //This upto your needs.
}
```

//UIStoryboardSegue to move over another controller accordingly.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.identifier {
    case "ShowDetail":
        if let ip = myTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
            if let svc = segue.destination as? DetailViewController{
                svc.selectedObject = (myCounters?[tempIndex])!
            }
        }
    default:
        print("error in segue")
    }
}
```